# Form with the VKB always open

Tags: codenameone

For a `Form` used for chatting, it could be nicer to have the VKB always opened (like in other chatting apps), because opening and closing the VKB after every message is annoying.

How can I achieve that with Codename One? I'm interest for that in a single `Form` only, in the other Forms the VKB should act normally. Thank you

Comment: I suppose that my question is equivalent to have a `TextArea` that never lose focus and keep the VKB open. I tried to override some method of `TextArea` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We minimize the keyboard when you click "done", back (on Android) or when you click on a different component to move focus away. This is pretty consistent with the way whatsapp works in terms of keyboard behavior. You can detect the last one and explicitly invoke `textField.startEditingAsync()` to reopen the keyboard.

Notice that a virtual keyboard is always tied to a text field.

Comment: This doesn't work: I can add `textField.startEditingAsync()` to the actionListener of the `TextField`, but this causes that the VKB is closed and then opened again. Moreover, this doesn't prevent the VKB to be closed when the contentPane is scrolled. I was referring to the Threema app, that keep the VKB open on iOS, even during the scrolling and after sending a message.

Comment: We'll need to add explicit support for that. Right now the VKB is closed implicitly. You can file an RFE on that but it probably won't go into the 7.0 timeframe

Comment: Solved: I have a Form inside a Form. Using `setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode(true);` in the outer form and in the inner form allows the user to scroll the contentPane keeping the virtual keyboard open, that is what I wanted. This solution work both on Android and iOS.